# Find the measure of the $PQ$ segment in the regular octagon below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

We have a regular octagon $ABCDEFGH$ with sides of equal length $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$, taking vertices $A, C$, and $E$ as centers, arcs of radii $AG, CA$, and $EG$ are drawn respectively, which intersect at points $P$ and $Q$ ($P$ and $Q$ being interior to the polygon). Calculate $PQ$.(Answer:($\sqrt3-1)$)

I made the drawing but I need to demonstrate that the $\angle PEO = 30^o$ or that the $\angle GPE = 150^o$. So I can finish because as the remarkable triangle we discover the radius $1$.

$\triangle PKO_{isosceles-rectangle)} \implies PK = OK$

$PQ = \frac{PK}{2}$

$ \triangle EPK: tg 30^o = \frac{PK}{1-PK}$ and it will be resolved

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that the triangles $\Delta ACP$ and $\Delta AGQ$ are equilateral by construction, all sides are congruent.

[image: MSE geometry problem in an octogon 4755360]

The constructions of $P,Q$ are symmetric / reflected (step by step) w.r.t. the line $AE$, which is a symmetry line of the given octogon. So $PQ\|GC$. (Since $G,C$ correspond by the same reflection.) The angle in $P$ between $PQ$ and $PC$ is thus
$$
\widehat{QPC} =
\widehat{PCG} =
\widehat{PCA} -
\widehat{GCA} =
60^\circ-45^\circ =15^\circ\ .
$$
We also know $
\widehat{ECA} =90^\circ$ in the octogon. (Or in the square $ECAG$.)
Changing the view, looking to the circle centered in $C$ with radius
$CA=CE$ we have thus the arc $\overset\frown{EA} = 90^\circ$. The angle
$
\widehat{EPA}$ is thus in measure $\frac 12\cdot 270^\circ=135^\circ$.
This shows that
$$
\widehat{EPQ} =
135^\circ-15^\circ-60^\circ=60^\circ\ .
$$
By the reflected argument, or by reflection, $\widehat{EQP} = 60^\circ$.

So $\Delta EPQ$ is equilateral, its angle in $E$ is $60^\circ$, and after drawing its bisector $EOA$ we obtain
$\widehat{PEO}=\frac 12\cdot 60^\circ=\bbox[yellow]{\ 30^\circ\ }$.

---

We have one objection, the above picture is the same as in the OP picture, but not exactly what the problem, taken mot-a-mot, wants:

[image: mse question 4755360]

To switch from one picture to the other one use a rotation of $90^\circ$ around the symmetry center of the octogon. (So instead of $\Delta EPQ$ from the solution and the first picture, we have now an equilateral triangle $\Delta GPQ$ in the second picture. And all the positions of the points $P,Q$ that can be obtained by similar constructions using the centers $A,C,E,G$ for the $90^\circ$ arcs are building a square.)

Comment: Not necessarily related to your answer, but where do you draw these graphs?

Comment: @bb_823 I am using geogebra. To draw the octogon, i told geogebra i want a regular polygon, gave two clicks in the landscape for the points $A,B$, and told i want $8$ sides. The octogon was in there. (Well, i had some previous setting for the brown color for the segments.) Then change the color for segments to green. (There is a tool box menu, tools are bundled in categories. The "decorations" for the objects, like color and label are somehow hidden in an extensible button near the right upper corner of the canvas.) Now i guessed that $EPQ$ is equilateral. So geo' please draw on $PQ$ a reg...

Comment: Thank you. I've only used it a few times to draw functions or sequences, but didn't know it was such a powerful tool.

Comment: Thanks for the help. but I made a mistake in the figure and it is repeated in yours. The center should be on $E$ and not on $G$. The position of $Q $would change but by geogebra the value of $PQ$ would not change

Comment: Thanks again.......................